# PHP closing connections when too many

Tags: php, apache, server-sent-events, event-stream, event-stream-processing

recently, I decided to load test my website on some page that require server sent events (event streams) which means that PHP needs to handle many opened connections (with scripts on loop). When approaching the ~140 opened connection, the connections started closing after 1 or 2 seconds. While doing the load testing I monitored my server and the CPU load was very low, RAM usage was low, Network was not the bottleneck so I know think that it may not be an hardware deficiency. Apache log showed no PHP warnings (neither fatal errors). Is there a parameter in the php ini file that may be responsable for closing connections?

If you need some logs or other I will try my best to provide them.

Thanks.

Comment: Apache has a limitiation when it comes to the amount of connections it will allow. So that might be the limiting factor in your case.

Comment: I would recommend that you move to nginx and php-fpm if you need many connections open at the same time.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am trying to use nginx however it is blocking event-streams when using tls... So I am stuck with apache here...